# Entry rollback on .create and .save because foreign_key "must exist", but won't accept a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, console, ruby-on-rails-5

My models are

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :event_options
end

class EventOption < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
end
```

In `rails c`, I can use this to create an `Event` just fine.

```
Event.create(name:"Face Painting", active:true)
```

However, when I do this:

```
EventOption.create(description:"You give us money. We paint your face.", price: 250.00, name: "People Painting 1", event: 1);
```

It gives me a rollback with the error:

```
 @details={:event=>[{:error=>:blank}]},
 @messages={:event=>["must exist"]}>
```

I try it with `event_id` and just `id` as well (as well as `:event_id/:event/:id => 1` and , but for some reason, none of them let me provide a link to the `EventOption` to the `Event` on creation.

Any clue?

Comment: Hey there. What happens when you type `EventOption` into your rails console? It should return all the columns that exist on the EventOption table. And one of these should be a foreign_key like `event_id`. You'll need to associate these in your database migrations, if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling that you haven't properly associated the database columns. In that case, you need to create a migration:

```
rails g migration AddForeignKeyToEventOptions
```

And then in the migration file you'll need to add a field for the event_id:

```
...
def change
  add_column :event_options, :event_id, :integer
end
...
```

Then you'll need to run your migrations:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Once these are properly associated you'll need to restart your console and then try associating your event_option with any event:

```
EventOption.create(
  description:"You give us money. We paint your face.",
  price: 250.00,
  name: "People Painting 1",
  event: 1     # Supposing that event with id: 1 exists.
)
```

**EDIT:**
Here's a link to the rails docs on creating migrations:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-migration

I'm looking at this section:

```
class AddUserRefToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :products, :user, foreign_key: true
 end
end
```

Comment: I end up getting this as I run that migration: `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "event_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist`

Comment: I'll update my answer. You're going to need to add the column for `event_id`.

Comment: Is that not already created on the :events table with :id by default? Or will I need to do an `add_column :event_options, :event_id`?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like it wants you to explicitly add the :event_id column. Which is strange as it should automagically add it for you if you referenced it when you created it.

Comment: That was my thought, too, which is why I got so confused at it not working and cam ehere. I'll do the migration with the column and see if that works, then if not, I'll do the foreign key add, too

Comment: Once I added the explicit column for `event_id` it worked, and they're linked because I was able to run `e = Event.first` and then `e.event_options` for it to pull up `Face Painting 1` as the result. You are a fantastic human being, James. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

`event = Event.create(name:"Face Painting", active:true)`

`EventOption.create(
    description: "You give us money. We paint your face.",
    price: 250.00, 
    name: "People Painting 1", 
    event: event 
)`

Also, unless you are combining two statements on one line, there's no need for semicolons in Ruby.

Comment: I think copy/pasting from the terminal did that with the semi-colon. I didn't even notice it. #sheepish